# Nodejs unable to call more than one instance of the web application due to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, mongodb

I have Nodejs web application running, the application based on user request - will make a call MongoDB, but at any point we are able to open only one page instance and process , if we make another request it fails with below error:

We found the issue due to Mongodb connection, Our application is unable to handle more than one mongo request. If multiple users request for home page we see this error. we start the application using command: "nodejs bin/www"
Feel like we are missing something very basic, in handling Mongo request . Please suggest. Any input on how to handle multiple requests - with process calls with node js  with mongodB?

Not Found
404
Error: Not Found
    at c:\app\test\app.js:129:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\app\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (c:\app\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at c:\app\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (c:\app\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (c:\app\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at form.parse (c:\app\test\node_modules\express-formidable\lib\middleware.js:17:7)
    at IncomingForm. (c:\app\test\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:107:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:208:7)

bin/www (file)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var app = require('../app');
var config = require('../config');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var debug = require('debug')('hornbill:server');
var http = require('http');
var assert = require('assert');
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '5007');
app.set('port', port);
/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
var server = http.createServer(app);
/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
MongoClient.connect(config.mongo_url, {
  poolSize: 20
},function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    app.locals.mongo = db.db(config.mongo_db);
    server.listen(port);
    console.log("inside app.js",app.locals.mongo.listCollections());
    //db.close();
    //module.exports.mongo=db;     
    }
);
//server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
server.timeout = 1000 * 60 * 10;
```

routes/home.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(process.cwd());
        const db = req.app.locals.mongo;
    db.listCollections({}).toArray(function(err, collInfos) {
              try {
                   res.render('home',{collection:collInfos});
                 }
              catch(err){
                 res.end();
                 console.log(err)}
                });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Show some code, please. It's really hard to debug without it.

Comment: my code for upload.js

Comment: ? I still don't see code